# Another Gson Polymorphism Query

Tags: java, generics, gson

Polymorphism perils pertaining to Gson have been asked before. But I am wondering about implementation specifics regarding a List of objects that are children of a super class. Look at the following example:

```
OrderForm createForm = ...;  //Instantiate master object that contains list of Questions
String json = m.gson().toJson(createForm);
System.out.println("#1 Order form rendered to: " + json);
System.out.println("#2 Qst list: " + m.gson().toJson(createForm.getQuestions()));
for(QuestionObject<?>q:createForm.getQuestions()) {
    if(q instanceof MultipleChoiceQuestion) {
        System.out.println("#3 Uncast question:" + m.gson().toJson(q) + "\n\n");
        MultipleChoiceQuestion t = (MultipleChoiceQuestion)q;
        System.out.println("#4 Cast question:" + m.gson().toJson(t) + "\n\n");
    }
}
```

This example shows 4 print statements that output 4 forms of the JSON-serialized object:

1. The entire object
2. Just a list inside of the object
3. A question inside of the list, just at the generic abstract class level
4. The same question, but this time cast to its specific type

In this case, **QuestionObject** is an abstract parent class. Different types of questions can extend this object, like **TextQuestion, MultipleChoiceQuestion, TrueFalse**.. you get the idea. The questions are all stored in a List by the order in which they're presented. A **MultipleChoiceQuestion** differs from its siblings in that it contains a list of choices that a user could select from (in this example "choices" contains 3 fruits). However, I'm having a hard time getting these to render into JSON.

Here's the output from the above code.

*The take away is that only the first println statement doesn't work* (translating an entire object that contains a list of QuestionObject, as it interprets everything as QuestionObject instead of the extending class). The Question Text "Pick up to 3" displays, but the choices do not. #2, #3 and #4, however, show the options for the MultipleChoiceQuestion type just fine:

```
#1 Order form rendered to: {
  "formName": "TestForm",
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionText": "Are you reading \"test\" question #1?"
    },
    {
      "questionText": "How old are you?"
    },
    {
      "questionText": "Pick up to 3"
    }
  ]
}
#2 Qst list: [
  {
    "isRequired": false,
    "questionText": "Are you reading \"test\" question #1?"
  },
  {
    "isRequired": false,
    "questionText": "How old are you?"
  },
  {
    "chooseOneOnly": false,
    "sortAlphabetically": false,
    "choices": [
      "Orange",
      "Apple",
      "Banana"
    ],
    "questionText": "Pick up to 3"
  }
]
#3 Uncast question:{
  "chooseOneOnly": false,
  "sortAlphabetically": false,
  "choices": [
    "Orange",
    "Apple",
    "Banana"
  ],
  "questionText": "Pick up to 3"
}


#4 Cast question: {
  "chooseOneOnly": false,
  "sortAlphabetically": false,
  "choices": [
    "Orange",
    "Apple",
    "Banana"
  ],
  "questionText": "Pick up to 3"
}
```

Is this by design, or is it a bug in Gson? If it's be design, can someone explain the purpose behind this logic? Abbreviated snippets of the model below:

```
public class OrderForm implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String formName;
    private ArrayList<QuestionObject<?>> questions;
    public ArrayList<QuestionObject<?>> getQuestions() {
        return questions;
    }

    public OrderForm setQuestions(ArrayList<QuestionObject<?>> questions) {
        this.questions = questions;
        return this;
    }
}   

public abstract class QuestionObject<T extends Answerable<?>> implements Serializable {

    private String questionText = null;

    public void setQuestionText(String inText) {
        questionText = inText;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return questionText;
    }
}

public class MultipleChoiceQuestion extends QuestionObject<MultipleChoiceAnswer> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2621426772513381609L;
    public static final int QUESTIONTYPE = 666;

    private List<String> choices;

    public void setChoices(List<String> choices) {
        this.choices = choices;
    }

    public List<String> getChoices() {
        return choices;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I put the important point in italics: why doesn't the first situation work? Notice that the "choices" element doesn't render from the first print statement, but it does from the subsequent 3.

Comment: "The take away is that only the first situation doesn't work" What is the "first situation"? What other situations do work? What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: My apologies if I wasn't clear but if you read the question I state the problem. There are 4 System.out.println statements in the above code and that's the "situation" I was referring to. The first print statement shows the entire object serialized using gson. It doesn't serialize correctly. The next three print statement serialize different parts of the object instance and they **do** serialize correctly. Why doesn't the first situation work?